# simple if/else form check(should be simple)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting a simple if/else that worked in a previous project. But I'm having trouble making it work in a new project.

I have trimmed it down to the simplest version here.

HTML:

```
<form name="mainForm" action="formProc.php" method="get"  id="mainForm" onSubmit="return allChecks();" >


<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){
    //formVars
    var name = $('#name');

function allChecks(){
    if(name.val()==""){
        alert("lopan"); 
        return false;
    }
    
        if(name.val()===""){
        alert("lopan"); 
        return false;
    }
    
        if(name.val()== null){
        alert("lopan"); 
        return false;
    }
return false;
}

});
</script>
```

I'm trying to force a "false" on the form but it still goes to the next page.

I also created another button in the form with type="button", declare it and used:

```
var btn= $('#clearF');
btn.click(allChecks);
```

This works, but I'm not sure why.

In troubleshooting, I noticed it went through to the next page. So I started trying to prevent it from going to the next page by adding validation to the fields. The goal is to block it from going to the next page unless valid.

Comment: In the first part of your code (where things DON'T work) you never actually call the `allChecks`. Did you just forget to bind it the way you did in part 2?

Comment: hello. if you look on the first set of html code i put above, push the scroll bar right) i call it on the forms "onsubmit = return allChecks();"

Comment: Yes, I just saw this, look at @Engineer's answer, this should solve your problem (the function is not defined in global scope)

Answer (score 3):

`allChecks` is not 'visible' for your markup. It is inside of `$(document).ready()` handler. To make it 'visible' just declare it like this:

```
window.allChecks=function(){
```

Comment: hello. if you look on the first set of html code i put above, push the scroll bar right) i call it on the forms "onsubmit = return allChecks();"

Comment: by `"markup"` I meant `onSubmit="return allChecks();"` this line. `allChecks` function is not on global scope.And when you are trying to call `allChecks` onsubmit event, it will not be called, as there is no such function.

Comment: ok i kinda understand what you are saying(im a noob so be patient lol) but, as i understand it, the .ready function means that when the document is ready, make these available, and the jquery object means that it makes it available anywhere on the page as oppose to say, doing all this in regular javascript and putting it on the bottom of the page to make sure it has access to the variables contents on load from top to bottom..so what am i not understanding? or misunderstanding between this and your "no such function" ? Thanks

Comment: `$(document).ready` just says that `DOM` is ready, and you can access any DOM Element in your markup,and it says nothing about "making objects available anywhere". For accessing objects(functions) you need to understand the scope of these objects. For more information you could read articles about javascript scope. For example http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 0):

instead of `onsubmit` on the markup, why not use jQuery in creating a handler?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mainForm').on('submit',function(){
        //whatever you want to do on submit
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle submit event this way:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    //formVars

    var name = $('#name');

    $("#mainForm").submit( function() {

    if ( name.val() === "" ) {
        alert("lopan");
        return false;
    }

    else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMg9V/1/

Answer (score 0):

Had something like that a while ago, productive code that suddenly changed behavior with submitting. What i now do is  in stead of your (fairly normal) code.

```
<form name="mainForm" action="formProc.php" method="get"  id="mainForm" >
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
var btn= $('#clearF');
btn.click(allChecks);

$(document).ready( function(){
    //formVars
    var name = $('#name');

function allChecks(){
    if(name.val()==""){
      alert("lopan"); 
      return false;
    }else{
      mainForm.submit();
    }
return false;
}

});
</script>
```